# no boot menu selection

Tags: dual-boot

installation through wubi went fine as per description (in the same partition as windows)
but when restarting, the computer never asks me to chose between ubuntu & windows
my machine : pc xp sp3 - 1Gb ram

what did I miss there ? should I have formated the disk with 2 partitions, then reinstalled windows on the first then ubuntu on the second ? this is not even mentioned in the guide !!!!

thks

Comment: Wubi installs Ubuntu **inside** Windows... It should appear as a program in the Windows menu or something...

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to install not from Wubi ? but from DVD or bootable USB.Here are the steps to install it from DVD or Bootable USB

> *Creating bootable media*

1-If you use DVD you can directly burn an Ubuntu ISO then boot it

2-If you want to use USB drive,you need some apps like *Universal USB Installer* or *rufus* to make a bootable USB

> *Preparing Partition and Installation*

1-Make a spare partition for Ubuntu from Windows by running `diskmgmt.msc`.Choose a partition to shrink (left-click and choose shrink) then insert the amount of the new partition.

2-After a new unallocated partition created,don't create a partition on it and now safe all your works and shutdown your computer then boot from your Ubuntu Installation media (you can change your boot configuration from BIOS)

3-Boot it up and wait till a window appeared and then choose "Install"

4-Follow the instruction,till you get option like "Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows".etc choose "Do something else" .A new window will appear

5-Choose your unallocated partition and click "+" there you will choose the mount point,the partition size and the filesystem,for the filesystem choose `ext4`
and i suggest to make more than one partition so you can make separate partition for other mount point and a partition with filesystem `swap` (well not all mount point should have a partition)

5.5-Make sure you've make a partition with mount point "/" because that mount point is equal to C: partition on Windows.And for the `swap` partition,it's equal to paging file on Windows,so theoretically with this partition on your HDD it will add a little for the memory peformance

6-After you finish with the partitioning stuff,you can proceed and follow the instruction

P.S.:After you installation done and reboot,restore your boot config. to previous state so it may to boot from HDD.